# Python Regex query for substring between the second occurrence of string A and string B

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I'm trying to parse some values from a raw output and having difficulties with the regex expression. The raw string contains two or more values with the same 'start' keyword. This is what I have so far, which gives me the first instance:

```
def parser(s, start, end):
    try:
        result = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), s).group(1).strip()
    except:
        result = ""
    print(result)
    return result
```

How do I get the second instance between the same 'start' and 'end'? Thanks in advance!

Example:

```
s = "verylongstring\n   Name Server: IDNS1.NETSOL.COM\n   Name Server: IDNS2.NETSOL.COM\n   Status: clientTransferProhibited...."
start = "Name Server: "
end = "\n"
```

Desired output:

```
server1 = IDNS1.NETSOL.COM
server2 = IDNS2.NETSOL.COM
```

I can get server1, but not 2.

```
server1 = parser(s, start, end)
```

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: If possible, please post input and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = "verylongstring\n   Name Server: IDNS1.NETSOL.COM\n   Name Server: IDNS2.NETSOL.COM\n   Status: clientTransferProhibited...."
start = "Name Server: "
end = "\n"
import re
re.findall(start + "(.*?)" + end, s)
```

The output is:

```
['IDNS1.NETSOL.COM', 'IDNS2.NETSOL.COM']
```

and the function can be like this:

```
def parser(s, start, end):
    result = [l.strip() for l in re.findall(start + "(.*?)" + end, s)]
    return result
```

for the same `s` `start` `end`:

```
>>>parser(s, start, end)
>>>['IDNS1.NETSOL.COM', 'IDNS2.NETSOL.COM']
```

Answer (score 1):

This works on the given example.

```
def parser(s, start, end):
    arr = [x.split(start)[1] for x in s.split('\n') if start in x]
    return arr
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) which will create an iterator that will be exhausted until the end of your string:

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = re.compile(r'Name Server:(?P<Server_Name>.*?)\n')
>>> 
>>> s
'verylongstring\n   Name Server: IDNS1.NETSOL.COM\n   Name Server: IDNS2.NETSOL.COM\n   Status: clientTransferProhibited....'
>>> 
>>> 
>>> for match in pat.finditer(s):
        print(match.group('Server_Name').strip())


IDNS1.NETSOL.COM
IDNS2.NETSOL.COM
>>> 
>>> [match.group('Server_Name').strip() for match in pat.finditer(s)]
['IDNS1.NETSOL.COM', 'IDNS2.NETSOL.COM']
```